# bash: capturing the output of set -v

Tags: bash

How many times have you seen someone trying to "Log the command I run and the output of the command"? It happens often, and for **seeing** the command you're running `set -v` is nice, (`set -x` is nice, too, but it can be harder to read), but what happens when you want to capture the command being run... but not **all** commands being run?

Running interactively I don't see a way to capture the `set -v` output at all.

```
set -v
echo a 1>/dev/null # 'echo a 1>/dev/null' is printed to the screen
echo a 2>/dev/null # 'echo a 2>/dev/null\na' is printed to the screen
```

I can put this in a script and things get better:

```
echo 'set -v'$'\n''echo a' > setvtest.sh

bash setvtest.sh 1>/dev/null # 'echo a' is printed to the screen
bash setvtest.sh 2>/dev/null # 'a' is printed to the screen
```

Aha, so from a script it goes to stderr. What about inline?

```
set +v
{ set -v ; echo a ; } 1>/dev/null # no output
set +v
( set -v ; echo a ; ) 1>/dev/null # no output
```

Hmm, no luck there.

Interestingly, and as a side note, this produces no output:

```
echo 'set -v ; echo a' > setvtest.sh
bash setvtest.sh 1>/dev/null
```

I'm not sure why, but perhaps that's also why the subshell version returns nothing.

What about shell functions?

```
setvtest2 () {
    set -v
    echo a
}

setvtest2               # 'a'
set +v
setvtest2 1>/dev/null   # nothing
set +v
setvtest2 2>/dev/null   # nothing
```

Now the question: **Is there a nice way to capture the output of `set -v`**?

Here's my not-nice hack, so I'm looking for something less insane:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

script=/tmp/$$.script
output=/tmp/$$.out

echo 'set -v'$'\n'"$1" >"$script"

bash "$script" 1>"$output"
cat "$output"
rm -f "$script" "$output"
```

Now I can execute simple scripts

```
bash gen.sh 'echo a' 1>/dev/null # prints 'echo a'
bash gen.sh 'echo a' 2>/dev/null # prints 'a'
```

But surely there are better ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run bash with option `-v` instead of turning on and off via `set`:

```
bash -v -c "echo a" 1>/dev/null # prints 'echo a'
bash -v -c "echo a" 2>/dev/null # prints 'a'
```

The dark side of this solution is that each such line will require to create new bash process, but you will not have to remember to switch off the `v` option back, since it's switched on only in a child process.

Comment: Now *that* is a lot less hacky. My workaround spawned a ton of bash processes anyway, so it's a straight improvement.

Comment: Given that no one seems to have a better idea, I'm accepting this one.

Comment: Can we also customize the '-v' output the same way we do with '-x' via PS4?

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o xtrace
Stuff.....
```

Comment: Out of scope! I'm not trying to solve the original problem, I'm trying to capture the output of `set -v`.

Comment: Perhaps you can call bash with the -o option it only passes that to the shell to be spawned. like bash -o xtrace gen.sh, then you can capture the output in stderr. I think set -v is the same as set -o verbose, so bash -o verbose gen.sh should do the job.